# If statement placement for user input(google apps script with code.gs, page.html, page-css.html,page-js.html)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I am creating a web app that allows the user to select their current department , which department they will be temporarily loaned to, the task they are doing, and the time spent on the task. I need to write some sort of statement that will determine the team they are on (current or new) based on the selection of their current department.

I have tried multiple placements of the "if statement" in various places

```
//// code for appending new row into sheet need to add "team" as the second ////variable    
function userClicked(userInfo){
    ws.appendRow([user,userInfo.department,userInfo.tempDepartment,userInfo.task,userInfo.timeSpent,new Date()]);
}

//// function for selecting the varibales that get appended into worksheet
function doStuff() {
    var userInfo = {};

    userInfo.department = document.getElementById('department').value;
    userInfo.tempDepartment = document.getElementById('tempDepartment').value;
    userInfo.task = document.getElementById('task').value;
    userInfo.timeSpent = document.getElementById('timeSpent').value;

    google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);

    document.getElementById('timeSpent').value='';
    var dpt = document.getElementById('department');
    dpt.selectedIndex=0;
    M.FormSelect.init(dpt);
    var tempDpt = document.getElementById('tempDepartment');
    tempDpt.selectedIndex=0;
    M.FormSelect.init(tempDpt);
    var task = document.getElementById('task');
    task.selectedIndex=0;
    M.FormSelect.init(task);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here. can you clarify?

Comment: I need to determine what team someone is on based on element id "department"
either "new" or "current"

Comment: There's no `if` statement in your code, what are you talking about?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to do some kind of database query, not an `if` statement.

Comment: @Barmar I don't have an up-to-date database to query from, it should be something simple like 
var dpt = userInfo.department;
var team = {};
if (dpt == "Refill") {
team == 'New';
}

Comment: So why doesn't that code work for you?

Comment: Is `team` supposed to be an object or a string? You're using it both ways.

Comment: @Barmar it's supposed to be a string that gets stored as a variable based on "department" then appended in the google sheet via ws.appendRow

Comment: Then why did you write `var team = {};`?

Comment: @Barmar because I have tried every possible way I can think of including trying to make it an object

Comment: How is the variable supposed to get into the sheet? It's not part of the `userInfo` object that `userClicked()` inserts.

Comment: @Barmar I tried using a "switch function" in my userClicked function and it returned no value

Comment: What's a "switch function"? Do you mean a statement like `switch(userInfo.department) { case "Refill": team = "New" }`?

Comment: How would that help? You need to add the value the row you're appending, like `ws.appendRow([user,userInfo.department,userInfo.tempDepartment,userInfo.task,userInfo.timeSpent,new Date(), userInfo.team]);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb trying to answer such a confusing question, but here's my attempt.

Add a `team` property to the `userInfo` object, fill it in with an `if` statement, and add it to the sheet when appending.

```
function userClicked(userInfo){
    ws.appendRow([user,userInfo.department,userInfo.tempDepartment,userInfo.team,userInfo.task,userInfo.timeSpent,new Date()]);
}

//// function for selecting the varibales that get appended into worksheet
function doStuff() {
    var userInfo = {};

    userInfo.department = document.getElementById('department').value;
    userInfo.tempDepartment = document.getElementById('tempDepartment').value;
    userInfo.task = document.getElementById('task').value;
    userInfo.timeSpent = document.getElementById('timeSpent').value;
    if (userInfo.department == "Refill") {
        userInfo.team = "New";
    } else {
        userInfo.team = "Old";
    }

    google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
    ...
```